# Compute $A^n v$ for any positive integer $n$ and vector $v$ for a specific matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Show how you can compute $\begin{pmatrix} 3 & -2 & 3 \\ 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 3 & 0 \end{pmatrix}^n v$ for any positive integer $n$ and any three-dimensional vector $v$. In particular, compute
>   $$\begin{pmatrix} 3 & -2 & 3 \\ 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 3 & 0 \end{pmatrix}^{10} \begin{pmatrix} 12 \\ 2 \\ -13 \end{pmatrix}.$$

I've discovered a few things about this 3D matrix:

1. It's eigenvectors are 
   $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix},\text{and} \begin{pmatrix} 11 \\ 1 \\ -14 \end{pmatrix}$$
   with corresponding eigenvalues 4, 2, and -1, respectively.
2. Any 3D vector can be written as a linear combination of those eigenvectors.

I feel like these pieces of information will help me out but I can't quite piece the puzzle together.

Comment: You have all the ingredients you need here. Write $v$ as a linear combination of eigenvectors. The matrix acts linearly, and you know how it acts on the eigenvectors, so you know how it acts on the linear combination. By the way, you've shown that $\mathbb{R}^3$ has a basis of eigenvectors for the action of the matrix, which is the same as saying it acts diagonalizably!

Comment: @RCT  I'm a bit confused.  How does the matrix act on the linear combination?  Does it act like a distribution?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Matrices encode linear transformations, and "linear" precisely means that it commutes with addition and scalar multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

Two other pieces which might be helpful:

1. If you arrange your eigenvalues in a diagonal matrix $D$, and corresponding eigenvectors as columns of a matrix $P$, then $AP = PD$, or $A = PDP^{-1}$.
2. If $A = PDP^{-1}$, then $A^n =  PD^n P^{-1}$.

If $D$ is diagonal, $D^n$ is pretty easy to compute.

Comment: If $D$ is diagonal, how would you compute the $D^n$?

Comment: @YunaKun: Try it and see.

Answer (score 0):

Let us call the eigenvectors $$v_4=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, v_2=\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix},\text{ and } v_{-1}=\begin{pmatrix} 11 \\ 1 \\ -14 \end{pmatrix}.$$
The only task you have is to write the vector 
$$v=\begin{pmatrix}12\\2\\-13\end{pmatrix}$$
(or any other vector for that matter) as a linear combination of these vectors; i.e.,  you need to find $c_4, c_2, c_{-1} \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$v= c_4 v_4+c_2 v_2+ c_{-1} v_{-1}.$$
This is a system of three linear equations with 3 unknowns, so I expect you know how to handle this.

Then $$A^{10} v = c_4 A^{10}v_4+c_2 A^{10}v_2+ c_{-1} A^{10}v_{-1}
= c_4 4^{10}v_4+c_2 2^{10}v_2+ c_{-1} (-1)^{10}v_{-1}.$$